# Find the max value in a number of cells and copy that value into another cell

Tags: vba, excel, range, max

I'm trying to find the max value in a number of cells and copy that value into another cell. I'd appreciate if you could help me because I have tried a lot of things and none of them have worked.

Here's my code:

```
Dim ROIrange As Range
Dim ROImax As Integer
For i = 1 To 30
      ROIrange = Range("E" & (i + 4), "H" & (i + 4), "K" & (i + 4), "N" & (i + 4), "Q" & (i + 4), "T" & (i + 4), "H" & (i + 4)).Select
      ROImax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ROIrange)
      Range("B" & (i + 4)).Value = ROImax
      Next
```

I have two problems:

1. Whenever I run it, the program says:
   [image]

and highlights the **Range** here:

```
ROIrange = Range("E"...
```

*(TROUBLESHOOTING I DID THAT DIDN'T WORK - feel free to skip)*

In my attempt to solve this, I changed the number of values I have in the range function from 7 to 2. This change allows the program to progress further but it ends up selecting a box which is not what I want because that involves the selection of other cells which I don't want evaluated.

However, even this program ran into a problem - I thought this was probably because the first row is completely empty (as will occur with the data set I'm working with sometimes and is unavoidable)

However, I changed it to start with i=2 which references a row that happens to have data. This simply resulted in this error:

[image]

Comment: Remove the `.Select` from the end.

Comment: And use the key word `Set` at the beginning: `Set ROIrange = Range("E" & (i + 4), "H" & (i + 4), "K" & (i + 4), "N" & (i + 4), "Q" & (i + 4), "T" & (i + 4), "H" & (i + 4))`

Comment: Thanks Scott. You're always very helpful. I'll try this.

Comment: Just caught a typo that I fixed. (The last H should have been a W.) Also, I tried this : `Set ROIrange = Range("E" & (i + 4), "H" & (i + 4)), "K" & (i + 4), "N" & (i + 4), "Q" & (i + 4), "T" & (i + 4), "W" & (i + 4))` and that line of code turned red in the program and it also doesn't work :(

Comment: Set at the beginning and remove .Select from the end as mentioned by Scott

Comment: @skkakkar I did that and it didn't work :(

Comment: The line turns red and a window pops up and says "Compile Error Syntax Error"

Comment: THe correct usage is ~Sub test()
Dim rr As Range
Set rr = ActiveSheet.Range("a1:a2")
MsgBox rr.Address
End Sub~ Please check accordingly.

Comment: Range does not allow this method, you want UNION:  `Set ROIrange = Union(Range("E" & (i + 4)), Range("H" & (i + 4)), Range("K" & (i + 4)), Range("N" & (i + 4)), Range("Q" & (i + 4)), Range("T" & (i + 4)), Range("W" & (i + 4)))`  I may have missed a `)` but you get the idea.

Comment: Or do what @RDJ says and combine it into one string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Set ROIrange = Range("E" & (i + 4) & ",H" & (i + 4) & ",K" & (i + 4) & ",N" & (i + 4) & ",Q" & (i + 4) & ",T" & (i + 4) & ",W" & (i + 4))
```

Place the range of cells together as a single string.